# Let $K⊂\mathbb{R}^d,d∈\mathbb{N}$ be compact and $ε>0$. Show that $∪_{x∈K},K_ε(x)$ is compact. [Updated Question]

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

Let $K⊂\mathbb{R}^d,d∈\mathbb{N}$ be compact and $ε>0$. Show that $∪_{x∈K},K_ε(x)$ is compact.

$K_ε(x)$ is a $ε$-ball in the form of $K_ε(x) = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^d
: ∥x-y∥ ≤ ε\} = \overline{B_ε(x)}.$

Does anyone have a proof on how to show the statement in the title?

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ? Moreover, I guess that in the definition of $K_\varepsilon (x)$, you mean $\|x\|<\color{red}\varepsilon $. Byt the way, your definition of $K_\varepsilon (x)$ is strange because $\{x\in \mathbb R^d\mid \|x\|<\varepsilon \}$ has no dependance on a fix element $x$. I think that you rather mean $$K_\varepsilon (x)=\{y\in \mathbb R^d\mid \|x-y\|\leq \varepsilon \}.$$

Comment: You are right, .... ≤ε is right and the definition makes much more sense if you change $∥x∥$ to $∥x-y∥$. Well the definition of compact sets is clear to me, but how to form a proof is unclear to me :|

Comment: If you let $A$ cover $\cup K_\epsilon$, then since each $K_\epsilon$ is compact, you can extract a finite subcollection of covers from $A$. So take those finite subcollection and take the finite union of them together and that produces a finite subcover of $\cup K_\epsilon$, proving the compactness of your union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(u_n)$ a sequence of $\bigcup_{x\in K}K_\varepsilon (x)$. We want to prove that $(u_n)$ has a convergent subsequence. Let $x_n\in K$ s.t. $u_n\in K_\varepsilon (x_n)$ for all $n$. Since $(x_n)\in K^{\mathbb N}$ there is a subsequence (still denoted $(x_n)$) that converges. Denote $x\in K$ its limit. Let $N$ big enough so that $|x_{n}-x|<\varepsilon  $ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, $$|u_{n}-x|\leq |u_{n}-x_{n}|+|x_{n}-x|\leq 2\varepsilon $$ for all $n\geq N$, and thus $(u_{n})$ is bounded. Therefore, $(u_n)$ has a convergence subsequence. Denotes $u$ its limit.

For all $n\in \mathbb N$, there is $m_n>n$ s.t. $|u_{m_n}-u|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $|x_{m_n}-x|<\frac{1}{n}$. In particular $$|u-x|\leq |u-u_{m_n}|+|u_{m_n}-x_{m_n}|+|x_{m_n}-x|\leq \frac{1}{n}+\varepsilon +\frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow}\varepsilon .$$ Therefore, $u\in K_\varepsilon (x)$. This prove that $\bigcup_{x\in K}K_\varepsilon (x)$ is sequentially compact, and thus compact.

Comment: What is $K^{\mathbb N}$? I think you mean $K$. And why is the limit of $(u_n)$ in $\bigcup_{x\in K}K_\varepsilon (x)$ ?

Comment: @PaulFrost: In general, for sets $A$ and $B$, the set $B^A$ is the set in function $f:A\to B$. In particular, $K^{\mathbb N}$ in the set of sequences in $K$. What would be the meaning of $(x_n)\in K$ ? I edited my answer for the fact that $u\in K_\varepsilon (x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Very creative proof in my oppinion!

Comment: Thanks ! However, these are very classical arguments :-) @Brolle

Comment: @Brolle: I edit my previous answer, there were a small mistake. Be sure to consider this last version, and not the previous one.

Comment: Yes ofcourse! :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the continuous  function $F: \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d \to  \mathbb  R^d$ given by $F(x,y) = x+y$.

The closed ball $\overline{B_ε(x)}$ is the set $ x +   \overline{B_ε(0)} $ for $B_ε(0)$ the closed ball centred at the origin.

It follows the set   $\bigcup_{x∈K}K_ε(x)=\bigcup_{x∈K}\overline{B_ε(x)}$ can be written $F\big (K \times \overline{B_ε(0)}\big)$.

But this is the image of a compact set under a continuous function. Hence it is compact.